# How to show only the existing data points on x axis of bar graph in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, axis

I need to simple plot `B` vs. `A` as bar plot in MATLAB, but I don't want my x axis showing completely from 1 to 274. I only need to show the existing data point on my x axis, which can be done easily in Excel as in the image below. How can MATLAB do this?

[image]

```
A=[1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  18  20  25  27  29  37  40  42  43  48  73  204 242 274];
B=[30   15  5   9   5   6   3   3   2   1   4   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1];
```

Comment: You need to create a bar plot `bar(B)` then label the Bar plot on the x-axis `set(gca,'xticklabel',A)`. I think A has to be converted to char cell array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set both `'XTick'` and `'XTickLabel'` axes properties:

```
bar(B);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',A)
set(gca,'XTick',1:numel(A));
xlim([0 numel(A)+1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an inelegant, but, nonetheless, working solution to your question:

```
x = [1,4, 6, 7]; % Your data
uni = unique(x)
yMax = length(find(x == mode(x))) + 1;
c = cell(1, length(uni));

c = strread(num2str(uni),'%s')

hist(1:length(uni));
axis([0 length(uni) 0 yMax])
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:length(uni));
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', c);
```

Basically, this plots the histogram as if the data were spread from 1 to the number of unique elements.  Then, it sets the tick marks at each histogram value.  Then, it labels each tick mark with the correct number.